# SQL: Combine Categories and Members in one select output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `Category` and `Member`:

```
Category:            Member:
+--Id--+--Name--+    +--Id--+--Name--+--CategoryId--+
|  1   |  Cat1  |    |  1   |  Mem1  |  2           |
|  2   |  Cat2  |    |  2   |  Mem2  |  2           |
|  3   |  Cat3  |    |  3   |  Mem3  |  1           |
+------+--------+    |  4   |  Mem4  |  3           |
                     |  5   |  Mem5  |  1           |
                     |  6   |  Mem6  |  3           |
                     +------+--------+--------------+
```

I would like to have a query that gives the following output:

```
Combined:
+--Name--+--IsCategory--+
|  Cat1  |  True        |
|  Mem3  |  False       |
|  Mem5  |  False       |
|  Cat2  |  True        |
|  Mem1  |  False       |
|  Mem2  |  False       |
|  Cat3  |  True        |
|  Mem4  |  False       |
|  Mem6  |  False       |
+--------+--------------+
```

I know how to use JOIN to output every Member with its Category name in one row and how to use UNION to list all Categories and Members in one output. Can I use a combination of these two commands to achieve the desired output? Or do I need to perform a FOR EACH loop somehow? Is it even possible to get what I want?

EDIT:
The order `Cat1, Mem3, Mem5, Cat2, Mem1, Mem2,...` is important for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers of @Chanukya and @Zohar Peled I found the following solution:

```
SELECT Name, IsCategory FROM
    (SELECT Name as Name, 1 as IsCategory, id * 10000 as OrderNumber
     FROM Category
     UNION ALL
     SELECT m.Name as Name, 0, c.id * 10000 + m.id as OrderNumber
     FROM Members b JOIN Category c ON m.CategoryId = c.Id
     ) AS temp
ORDER BY OrderNumber;
```

This assumes that there are no more than 10000 members per category, which is fine for my current use case. However, I appreciate any suggestions for a more elegant and correct way.

Answer (score 1):

JUST i tried like this  can u check it

```
CREATE TABLE  #Category  
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(4))

INSERT INTO  #Category 
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Cat1'),
    (2, 'Cat2'),
    (3, 'Cat3')

CREATE TABLE   #Member
    ([Id] int, [Name] varchar(4), [CategoryId] int)
;

INSERT INTO   #Member
    ([Id], [Name], [CategoryId])
VALUES
    (1, 'Mem1', 2),
    (2, 'Mem2', 2),
    (3, 'Mem3', 1),
    (4, 'Mem4', 3),
    (5, 'Mem5', 1),
    (6, 'Mem6', 3)

SELECT NAME , CASE WHEN NAME LIKE'%CAT%' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  AS IS_CATEGORY FROM (SELECT  * FROM #MEMBER  UNION ALL
SELECT *,NULL AS COLUMN1 FROM  #CATEGORY )A
```

output

```
NAME    IS_CATEGORY
Mem1    FALSE
Mem2    FALSE
Mem3    FALSE
Mem4    FALSE
Mem5    FALSE
Mem6    FALSE
Cat1    TRUE
Cat2    TRUE
Cat3    TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. The order (category name, member names, category name, membersnames,...) is important. See the edited answer.

Comment: @tell me one proper reason that how this order  will come i need explanation Cat1, Mem3, Mem5, Cat2, Mem1, Mem2..@Michael Hilus

Comment: The order needs to be like this: `Cat1` is the first category followed by all its members `Mem3` and `Mem3`. `Cat2` is the second category followed by its members `Mem1` and `Mem2` and so forth...

Comment: @MichaelHilus how w e know  that cat1 is followed by Mem3 and Mem5
why cant  mem1 and mem 2

Comment: Because of the field `CategoryId` in table `Category`. The requirements are that all members of a category are followed by the category.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union for this:

```
SELECT name, 0 as IsCategory
FROM member
UNION ALL
SELECT name, 1
FROM category
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The order of the names in the output is important for me. See the edited answer.